# What's the difference between PIL, cv2, matplotlib for loading and saving the image in terms of image quality?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, opencv

I have no idea why their have many choice to saving and loading the image in python. So I suppose that various method for operating the image may result different image quality or the time complexity.

package example.
e.g. (PIL.imread, PIL.imwrite ), (cv2.imread, cv2.imwrite), (_, plt.savefig)

Could someone give me some advice or suggestion for practices view, and I also attempt to know why as the title described.

Thank you very much ~~

Comment: The differences in image quality are probably the *least* important difference between the packages - more important are the capabilities and ease of use of each.  In fact I wouldn't expect to see any difference in just reading and writing images except perhaps for the JPEG format.

Comment: Also be aware that as long is development is still occurring on any of these packages, image quality could change overnight.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Actually I want to confirm the each procedure in the preprocessing is exactly same as the other code. 
But I think it may be subtle difference with various package for saving and loading the image as you said. (except JPEG format)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  JPEG is a lossy format, so it's normal and expected that different implementations will give slightly different results; there's no objective way to say one implementation is more correct than another.  For non-lossy formats the results should always be identical once you've read the image back in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Did you mean it's not related with the library, but for the format to store the image? The package may use some way for processing the image, but the method to decode and encode the byte information into the corresponding format will be the same.

Comment: Different libraries may of course use different code to generate a file.  Those files probably won't be bit-for-bit identical because the file specifications allow for flexibility.  But that won't matter, what matters is the image you get when you read the file back in.  If those aren't identical for a non-lossy format, the library is broken.